# ImportError cannot import name '_ccallback_c'

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do this problem that I saw in a YouTube video and I get this error every time I try to import scikit-learn. I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I installed scikit-learn through Anaconda.

This is the error message I get.

[image: This is the error message I get]

I've already uninstalled and installed sckit-learn and scipy using conda isn't all multiple times but I always get the same result.

Please, help.

Comment: Do you have another python version other than the conda installation?

Comment: Paste the code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. uninstall scipy using `pip uninstall scipy`
2. re-install scipy using `pip install scipy`